# First Order Logic simplification for sentences with multiple quantifiers

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

**Background**

I’m having problems translating some more complicated questions using First Order Logic. I’m wondering if there are any ways to simplify sentences that are very long with lots of quantifiers.

For example, in the question below, I am finding it very difficult to understand how to write this sentence out in English as there are so many quantifiers in this single sentence.

**Problem**

> [image]
> [image]

**Thoughts**

I would be grateful for any advice on how to simplify something like this, as trying to simplify a sentence with this many conditions in my head is very difficult for me to wrap my head around.

I understand how to translate these types of sentences in general. My problem isn't with the process of translation, it is more specifically related to how to tackle large problems such as the one above that are difficult to logically work through without breaking the problem down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

I'd recommend you work inside-out. Here are a few to get started.

On the antecedent, we will ignore the universal quantifier:
$$Person(x)\wedge \exists y(City(y)\wedge LivesIn(a,y)\wedge LivesIn(x,y)$$

Translates to

> There is a Person who lives in the same city as Alex.

On the consequent side, we've got a lot going on. Let's go all the way in to

$$City(w)\wedge Likes(x,w)\rightarrow y=w$$

> If Person x likes City w then y = City w

Note here that I've left $y$ unspecified since we haven't worked ourselves outwards enough to where we fix $y$.

Just go snippet by snippet like this. Leave the external quantifiers alone until you've figured out the inner parts.

Then you can put them together to get to a coherent English statement.